# Girlfriend is in Cameroon and I want her to join me in Germany

Tags: germany, family, schengen, marriage

I am looking at this https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/kurzmeldungen/EN/2020/08/einreise-unverheirateter-paare-en.html

It looks promising for me to bring my fiance from Cameroon to Germany. I have German citizenship but at the moment the German embassy in Cameroon is not giving Schengen visas in Cameroon. Any ideas on what I can do to help bring my fiance that I will marry to Germany? Any lawyers or  firms that handle such a case? I am willing to contact them.

Comment: A visa for a fiancee to travel to Germany and marry there is not a "Schengen visa" in the usual sense, but instead a "national visa."  Are you sure that they're also not processing national visas?

Comment: Girlfriend? Or fiance? I ask because there is a BIG difference, especially as far as visas are concerned.